# JQquery data table warning when table is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have this warning

> DataTables warning (table id = 'datatabledetail'): Unexpected number
>   of TD elements. Expected 3 and got 0. DataTables does not support
>   rowspan / colspan in the table body, and there must be one cell for
>   each row/column combination.

when my table is empty,

what must I do ??

this my code for datatable

```
var oTableDetail = $('#datatabledetail').dataTable({
        "bSort": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "mDataProp": "Id", "bVisible": true },
                        { "mDataProp": "CodeValue", "bVisible": true },
                        { "mDataProp": "NameValue", "bVisible": true }
        ]//
        ,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
                            {
                                "fnRender": function (o) {
                                    return "<center>  <input type='button' id='" + o.aData['Id'] + "' class='cremove mws-button blue' value='Remove'></center>";
                                },
                                "aTargets": [0]
                            }
        ]
    });
```

this my code in html

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="mws-table" id="datatabledetail"
                               width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 5%;">
                                        Action
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 40%;">
                                        Food Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;">
                                        Food Code
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: show datatable code...

Comment: You can set a condition if you got some data than apply datatable otherwise do not apply datatable simply show the empty table.

Answer (score 0):

in DataTable library you can't use any attribute rowspan or colspan in your html tag and make sure that your number of column between table heading and table body is match, ex:

```
<table id="xyz">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Heading 1</th>
       <th>Heading 2</th>
       <th>Heading 3</th>
       <th>Heading 4</th>
     <tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
     <tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
     <tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
     <tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td>Content</td>
     <tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```